# How to center HTML5 Videos?

Tags: css, html, video

I'm just messing around with some HTML5, and I was trying to center a video on the page. For some reason I can't get it to center. I've tried to add a class to the video tag itself, and I've wrapped the video in a separate `div`. However, the video stays on the left.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/css">
    .center {
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="center">
      <video controls="controls">
        <source src="/media/MVI_2563.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I know this must be something I'm overlooking in the wee hours of the morning, but any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: may be you have define width in your .center class

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The center class must have a width in order to make auto margin work:

```
.center { margin: 0 auto; width: 400px; }
```

Then I would apply the center class to the video itself, not a container:

```
<video class='center' …>…</video>
```

Comment: I've added width. Removed the class from the div, and added it to the video tag. Still no luck! I think something else is going on here, because even adding styles to change the background color of the body is doing nothing. It's odd.

Comment: Are you using IE6 without a proper DOCTYPE? There is no other reason I could think of this doesn't work. Could you share your code with us on http://jsfiddle.net with CSS and HTML? Oh, and have you included the stylesheet?

Comment: I'm using FF4, Chrome11, and IE9. Also, the styles are embedded, so there's no external style I'm forgetting to include. http://jsfiddle.net/8cXqQ/  I changed it to include a width as people here mentioned, and I removed the div, and added the class to the video tag itself.

Comment: you are missing the `display: block;` style which is needed to actually center the tag

Comment: @zgr024 - that did it!  display: block; is what i was missing.

Answer (score 46):

HTML CODE:

```
<div>
 <video class="center" src="vd/vd1.mp4" controls poster="dossierimage/imagex.jpg" width="600">⁪</video>
</div>
```

CSS CODE:

```
.center {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block
}
```

Comment: could you add more comments to this?

Comment: Although he didn't comment it, I could try explain - also this is the right answer, only one that worked for me.

From @djpMusic, he says video and audio elements are actually inline elements rather than block, so using "display: block;" you are explicitly saying it is a block element and therefore you can apply margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; to make them centered within their container.

Answer (score 41):

I was having the same problem, until I realized that `<video>` elements are *inline elements, not block elements*. You need only set the container element to have `text-align: center;` in order to center the video horizontally on the page.

Comment: Ahh, man...  Web dev is amazing these days.  I put "text-align: center" on something, and the contents get centered.  Wow.  When I started, I had to support all major browsers, including IE4, 5, 5.5, 6 and 7 (which were each a project in themselves).  At the time, CSS stood for "Can't Style Shit" :D what a wonderful world.

Answer (score 17):

Do this:

```
<video style="display:block; margin: 0 auto;" controls>....</video>
```

Works perfect! :D

Comment: Thanks for inline, when not using css.

Answer (score 7):

I will not prefer to center just using video tag as @user142019 says. I will prefer doing it like this:

```css
.videoDiv
{
    width: 70%; /*or whatever % you prefer*/
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="videoDiv">
  <video width="100%" controls>
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
</div>
```

This will make your video responsive at the same time the panel for controls will have the same size as the video rectangle (I tried what @user142019 says and the video was centered, but it looked ugly in Google Chrome).

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem. This worked for me:

```
.center {
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width: 400px;
    **display:block**
 }
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, I was having the same problem. And for some reason no body pointed it out.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
video {
display:block;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

@snowBlind In the first example you gave, your style rules should go in a <style> tag, not a <script> tag:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .center {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
</style>
```

Also, I tried the changes that were mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879209/how-to-center-html5-videos/5879280#5879280) (see results at http://jsfiddle.net/8cXqQ/7/), but they still don't appear to work.

You can surround the video with a div and apply width and auto margins to the div to center the video (along with specifying width attribute for video, see results at http://jsfiddle.net/8cXqQ/9/).

But that doesn't seem like the simplest solution...shouldn't we be able to center a video **without** having to wrap it in a container div?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my error with 'style' vs 'script'. I know that CSS should be wrapped in a style tag, but must have just typed script on accident and didn't notice it.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem in revamping a web site in Dreamweaver. The site structure is based on a complex set of tables, and this video was in one of the main layout cells. I created a nested table just for the video and then added an `align=center` attribute to the new table:

```
<table align=center><tr><td>
    <video width=420 height=236 controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">
        <source src="video/video.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'/>
        <source src="video/video.webm" type='video/webm' >
        <source src="video/video.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
        <p class="sidebar">If video is not visible, your browser does not support HTML5 video</p>
    </video>
</td></tr></table>
```

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is set you video tag to `display:block;` FTW the default is `inline-block` FTL.

Try this

```
.center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: (whatever you want);
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a width in percent, you can do this :

```css
video {
  width: 50% !important;
  height: auto !important;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <video controls>
    <source src="http://www.nasa.gov/downloadable/videos/sciencecasts-_total_eclipse_of_the_moon.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
  </video>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use margins `<video>` is an inline element so you'll have to add `display block;`to your **css** class.

You can use specific with, but I wouldn’t use px values. Use % to make it responsive, like:

```
width: 50%;
```

That’ll make the video half of the viewport width.

See the original documentation here O World Wide Web Consortium [W3C](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/display)

**mystyle.css**

```css
video {
      width: 50% !important;
      height: auto !important;
      margin: 0 auto;
      display: block;
    }

    h1 {
      text-align: center;
      color: #C42021;
      font-size: 20px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
           <head>
              <meta charset="UTF-8">
              <title>Test</title>
               <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
           </head>
           <body>
              <h1>
                 How do you center a video 
              </h1>
              <div class="center">
                 <video controls="controls">
                    <source src="https://repositorio.ufsc.br/xmlui/bitstream/handle/123456789/100149/Vídeo%20convertido.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                 </video>
              </div>
           </body>
        </html>
```

See the code ready here for more understanding.

[You can view the code online Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Renatoch/1day07j8/)

Answer (score 1):

```html
<center>
    <video controls width="100%" height="480">
        <source src="video.mp4" type=video/mp4>
    </video>
</center>
```

Encapsulate your `<video>` within `<center></center>` tags, `<figure></figure>` also works.

Answer (score 0):

```
.center { width:500px; margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this page while trying to center align a pair of videos. So, if I enclose both videos in a center `div` (which I've called central), the margin trick works, but the width is important (2 videos at 400 + padding etc)

```
<div class=central>
    <video id="vid1" width="400" controls>
        <source src="Carnival01.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video> 

    <video id="vid2" width="400" controls>
        <source src="Carnival02.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>

<style>
div.central { 
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 880px; <!--this value must be larger than both videos + padding etc-->
}
</style>
```

Worked for me!

Answer (score -1):

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <h1 align="center">
      <video width="1000" controls>
        <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Specifying widths like this will not take care of the aspect ratio.

Answer (score -1):

If you use bootstrap, you can use d-block and m-auto classes.

```html
<video class="d-block m-auto" width="1100px" control> 
<source src="...." type="video/mp4" /> 
</video>
```