# Horizontal centralization of HTML5 video tag

Tags: css, html5-video

I am developing a dashboard, using angular.js and it contains of several videos. The dashboard allows the user to choose which size each of the videos should be in (small, medium, large). I like to centralize the videos, and have tried severals options (included here: [How to center HTML5 Videos?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879209/how-to-center-html5-videos)) , but cannot make any of them work... Can someone please help me?

JS:

```
$scope.videos = { videosArray: budilVideoArray(), colsize: { small: 'col-md-4', medium: 'col-md-6', large: 'col-md-12'}}

function buildVideoArray() {
    return [
        {
        name: 'video1',
        path: 'src/path/to/video/video1.mp4',
        size: 'col-md-6'
    },
    {
        name: 'video2',
      path: 'src/path/to/video/video2.mp4',
      size: 'col-md-6'
    }
    ]
}

$scope.resize = function (video, size) {
    video.size = $scope.vidos.colsize[size];
}
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="video in videos.videosArray">
  <div class="row">
    <input type="radio" name="radioButton-{{video.name}}" ng-click="resize(video, 'small')"> small
    <input type="radio" name="radioButton-{{video.name}}" ng-click="resize(video, 'medium')"> medium 
    <input type="radio" name="radioButton-{{video.name}}" ng-click="resize(video, 'large')"> large 
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div ng-class="video.size">
      <video class="video_attr" id="{{video.name}}">
        <source src="{{video.path}}" type="video/mp4"> 
      </video>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.video_attr {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found my solution after a while. Here is it:

## HTML:

```
<div class="row row-center">
    <div ng-repeat="video in videos.videosArray" class="{{video.size}} col-center">
        <video class="video_attr" id="{{video.name}}" src="{{video.path}}" preload="auto"> </video> 
    </div>
</div>
```

## CSS:

```
.row-center {
    text-align:center;
}
.col-center {
    display:inline-block;
    float:none;
}
.video_attr {
    width: 100%;
}
```